# How to create a sales contract in pdf, with the data generated by ws and download in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Can you tell me about your experience,

1. how to create a sales contract in pdf format with the data obtained
   from the webservice
2. how to print this contract
3. how to download a pdf format for this contract

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your webservices is sending back some kind of json response you can use :

> jsPDF - https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF.

Its a simple and easy to use library, here is an plunker which may help you ~ illustrating a small similar example for all the 3 points that you have mentioned:

```
https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/a1zal2
```

You can also visit their github page where they have mentioned various other methods that you may use as per your need / requirement.